# Запретить обновление Activity при повороте экрана

Tags: android

Как запретить обновление Activity при повороте экрана?

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: На удивление работает, в интернете перерыл кучу сайтов, везде массивно изменяют java, а оказывается так просто. Есть подводные камни?

Comment: перестроение лэйаута не будет происходить, потому нельзя будет как в Gmail app отображать то выдвижное меню, то всегда открытое при ландшафтном положении. Ещё вроде с табами ActionaBar будут проблемы. 
Думаю ещё с 5-к проблем наберется)

Comment: Подводные камни ? С точки зрения гугла, это называется bad praсtice, когда мы ставим такую, заглушку-костыль, зато на остальное закрываем глаза, особенно новички на это попадают, когда при повороте не обрабатывают сохранение/восстановление состояний.